# How can I supplement the "environment" details provided by JMC (Jira Mobile Connect)?

Tags: ios, jira-mobile-connect

I'm using JMC to collect feedback in an iOS application. I want to supplement the environment details it provides by adding in the ID of the logged-in sales rep. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to edit the `environment` data that's sent to JIRA, but I have found that if you supply an implementation for the `customFields` method via a `JMCCustomDataSource` you can supply a dictionary of values to send. These are sent to JIRA as custom field values. For my purposes, I created a custom field called `Sales Rep` and sent the logged-in rep's username via the `customFields` dictionary. Worked perfectly.